# check database connection on startup in spring

Tags: spring

I want to check db connection while spring application is being started ie when application context is getting generated. I plan to do this in a separate class(say class Checker) which will have a reference to the connection object(or its wrapper) that needs to be checked. If the connection is successful, the startup process continues, otherwise its aborted. The question is around the instantiation of class Checker. Should this be done with `new Checker()` or should this be created as `@Bean` whose `init` method performs this check.

Comment: Why don't configure a dataSource bean ?  If the DB cannot be connection , spring also will not start

Comment: That is done by the connection pool already... Startup will fail if it cannot connect to the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using jedis cluster and it doesn't do that.

Comment: The connection pool will start the minimum number of connections (I'm assuming you are using a proper connection pool like HikariCP. Using something like `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't to be used for production as that will create connections on the fly. Also apparently your question is about Redis and not a JDBC connection (judging by the fact that you are using a jedis cluster)...

Answer (score 1):

Use the helper to get the bean :

```
public class SpringContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
        public static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            SpringContextHolder.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    }
```

Now you can use the static context like `SpringContextHolder.applicationContext.getBean(name).`